# Concatenate array on loop php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => My name
            [1] => is
            [2] => John
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => My name is Jane
        )
```

how to achieve this kind of output see below. If the array count is greater than one I want to combine them as one.

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => My name is John
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => My name is Jane
        )
```

here is my code but it didn't work

```
foreach ($myArr as $key => $value) {
    if (count($myArr[$key]) > 1) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            $myArr[$key] .= $v; 
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: What is it returning right now?

Comment: I got this error @AmitMerchant `Notice:  Array to string conversion`

Comment: `$myArr[$key]` is still a reference to the inner array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use implode?

```
$data = [['my name', 'is', 'John'],['my name is Jane']];
$results = [];
foreach ($data AS $id=>$datum)
    if (count($datum) > 1)
        $results[$id] = implode($datum, ' ');
    else
        $results[$id] = $datum[0];
```

results:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "my name is John"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "my name is Jane"
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up for using `implode()`.

Comment: Nice, should work with normal array too, does seem like associative array is redundant.

Comment: ```
<?php

$data = [['my nameJohn'],['my name is Jassadasdsadsadane']];
$results = [];
foreach ($data AS $datum)
    if (count($datum) > 1)
        $results[] = implode($datum, ' ');
    else
        $results[] = $datum[0];

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);
    echo "</pre>";

Comment: My code was just storing the results in the same key as the source. Because the source is a numerically-indexed array, you could theoretically ditch the [$id] assignment, but it's no slower and will inherently respect arbitrary key values, which could be relevant if you had filtered the source array for some reason to remove some entries, or had string keys

Comment: `$results` is still the  same as in OP. Op did not use any associative array

Comment: I believe he was just referring to the fact that I am specifying the value of the keys instead of allowing them to be auto-assigned, as in `$results[] = $stuff;`

Comment: @sorak, spot on, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it would be like this:

```
foreach ($myArr as $key => $value) {
    if (count($myArr[$key]) > 1) {
        $myArr[$key][0] = '';  
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            $myArr[$key][0] .= $v; 
        }
        array_splice($myArr[$key], 1, count($myArr[$key])-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: the output would be the same

Comment: Did you check it?

Comment: Yes I checked it

Comment: For me It's working: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/67c481a4b3b100ee4b3fd52cb8591cb2d4e7e334

Comment: <?php

$data = [['my nameJohn'],['my name is Jassadasdsadsadane']];
$results = [];
foreach ($data AS $datum)
    if (count($datum) > 1)
        $results[] = implode($datum, ' ');
    else
        $results[] = $datum[0];

    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($results);

    echo "</pre>";

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it would be like this:

```
$ary[0] = Array("My name","is","John");
$ary[1] = Array( "My name is Jane" );
$i=0;       
foreach ($ary as $ar_item)  {
    $merged="";
foreach  ($ar_item as $ar_subitem)  
{
    $merged=$merged.$ar_subitem." ";
}
$ary[$i]=$merged;
$i++;
}
var_dump($ary);
```